# How to push new viewcontroller when click on tableview cell row?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am totally new guy (3 days fresher) in SWIFT programming.
I have created one sample tableview cell demo in swift.
I have used "Testviewcontroller" with xib.

## code is

```
import UIKit


class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var myTableview:UITableView!

    let fruits = ["Apple","Banana","Grapes","Chiku","Watermalon","Bear"]
    let blogSegueIdentifier = "TestViewController"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return self.fruits.count
    }
    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "MyTestCell")
        cell.textLabel?.text = self.fruits[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {

        let testVC = TestViewController(nibName : "TestViewController" , bundle:nil)
        navigationController?.pushViewController(testVC, animated: true)

        print("You have selected \(indexPath.row) row")
    }

}
```

## Appdelegate

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return true
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }


}
```

## My question is

I have used "didSelectRowAt indexPath" delegate method.
I am not able to push new view controller
Please help me guys i am not able to solve this.

Comment: what the error u facing , are you using storyboard or xib for layout

Comment: @ Harshal Valanda:I have used XIB file ,Is it useful in my case?

Comment: Embed you viewcontroller in Navigation controller. from Editior -> EmbedIn -> UInavigationcontroller

Comment: What happens when you tap on the row ? Are you using storyboard ? if yes then make sure that you have embeded in a navigation controller.

Comment: Do you already have a hierarchy setup like `UIWindow->UINavigationController->ViewController` and then you are calling `navigationController?.pushViewController` from `ViewController`? Perhaps you  did not setup UINavigationController and since you called `navigationController?.pushViewController` with an optional `?` so the call to nil ignored silently ?

Comment: @umair Afzal & Anbu.karthik :Nothing happened just give me message you have selected this row

Comment: is this controller your root viewController ? if yes then show appDelegate

Comment: @ NeverHopeless:I do not know how to set up this hierarchy

Comment: Checkout this `https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-from-scratch-with-swift-navigation-controllers-and-view-controller-hierarchies--cms-25462` for a start. See how author setup the storyboard and pushes new controller(s). Author using storyboard you can also setup these things from code too. I was talking about code technique.

Comment: @NeverHopeless :Page not Found

Comment: @hd1344 After all, you have to make sure that "didSelectRowAt indexPath" delegate method called.

Comment: byJeevan :This method gives me a message "You have selected this row.."Thanks

Comment: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-from-scratch-with-swift-navigation-controllers-and-view-controller-hierarchies--cms-25462

Answer (score 1):

As your using XIB for each `UIViewController`, you need to add the following code in your `AppDelegate.swift` file then you can access `navigationController` in your `ViewController.swift`.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        let viewController = ViewController(nibName:"ViewController", bundle:nil)

        let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: viewController)

        self.window!.rootViewController = navController

        self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
        return true

}
```

Comment: Not Working ,Gives me Black Screen.

Comment: My requirements is when i click on row of tableview cell then and then open new view controller.Sorry i Do not know how to do this .I am totally new.If it is in Objective c its very simple.

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/******/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/E88F5A80-1793-4593-A27F-77FB561904EA/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/ED218E72-DC6A-4E9A-85FB-D7D5A6413877/TableView.app> (loaded)' with name 'ViewController''      /////Crash

Comment: Don't you have XIB file for ViewController.swift file?

Comment: obviously I have xib file

Comment: Check, you're pointing to correct XIB, ViewController(nibName:"<YOUR XIB FILE>", bundle:nil)

Answer (score 0):

I think you dot not have a navigationController. If this viewController is your rootViewController you can do something like this in your appDelegate.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

let navController = UINavigationController()
let yourViewContoller = YourViewController()

navController.viewControllers = [yourViewContoller]

self.window?.rootViewController = navController
return true

}
```

Make sure that your have written init in your viewController like this

```
    init() {
    super.init(nibName: "YourViewController", bundle: Bundle.main)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that Navigation controller is nil in your case. Click on your xib file. Click on main View. Go to `Editor` menu, click on `Embed in`, select `Navigation controller`.